# How can i add subset to set in python

Tags: python, set, subset

i can't add set to python

you can add tuple to python set

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
a.add((10,11,12))
```

when i try same with set

```
a={1,2,3,4,5}
a.add({10,11,12})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: What result do you want? `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12}`, or `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, {10, 11, 12}}`? The latter is what this code tries to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `frozenset`s to a `set`, since they are hashable (because they are immutable).

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5}
a.add(frozenset([10,11,12]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd assume you are trying to get:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12}
```

You are appending a set which is unhashable. And when you add the tuple you will get:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (10, 11, 12)}
```

You are trying you get the union:

```
a.union({10,11,12})
```

Or:

```
a | {10,11,12}
```

Comment: `|` you mean, don't you ?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was a quick post. I edited.